# Fluid mechanics Grashoff number

Tags: fluid-dynamics, convection

When I derived the [Grashof number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grashof_number) (for natural convection at a vertical plate) starting with the ratio of buoyancy forces to viscous forces, I realized that I had set the Reynolds number to 1 (ie I had to set velocity*length/kinematic viscosity = 1) to get the accepted equation. Why is that?

Comment: Perhaps it's because the derivation used a dimensional analysis argument and the Reynolds number is dimensionless? Perhaps you could supply the specific equation you are trying to derive as well as your attempted argument. Otherwise, there's no way for us to judge for certain what happened.

Comment: It seems that there are  $2$ different regimes, free (or natural) convection, and forced convection. The free   convection regime is described by the [Grashoff number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grashof_number)= $\frac{buoyancy~ forces}{viscous~ forces}$, while the forced convection regime is described by the [Reynolds number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number)= $\frac{inertial~ forces}{viscous~ forces}$. There is a number, the [Richardson number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson_number) = $\frac{Grashof}{(Reynolds)^2}$, which help you to find in what regime you are.

Comment: Definition of Grashof number does not even contain velocity. So you probably have to explain why you 'had to set' Reynolds number to 1. Were you, by chance, trying to obtain similarity solution?